# Google Sheets - Find Consecutive Non Blanks

Tags: google-sheets

Hopefully quite a simple query.

[image]

I need to know if there are any consecutive non-blanks in each row.

***EG: Row 1 and Row 3 do, but row 2 does not.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("11",JOIN("",IF(A1:F1<>"",1,0)))),"Has consecutive","Hasn't consecutive"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats it, thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Rick If it works then please mark it as accepted (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

The first option, I think you can use a canditional formatting, with a custom formula. Like if A1 and A2 are not empty turn them red, if they are empty turn them green.

Another option:

First, you need to decide which of the 2 options you will use (COUNTA or SUMPRODUCT,) and use an if to count the 2 cells if they are not blank.

For example:

If A1 and A2 are not blank, then you count them, on the next row, if A2 and A3 are not blank count them.

**Count Cells If Not Blank Using COUNTA Function**

This is an example of how to use COUNTA:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A3)
```

However, and mentioned in the document. If there is a especial character in the cell, even if it looks empty it will be counted with that formula.

**Count Non-Empty Cells Using SUMPRODUCT Function**

This is an example of how to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(TRIM(A2:A3))&gt;0)
```